# can we instantiate an object of a class just declared and passed to a method in another class

Tags: c#

I am implementing an auto mapper and stuck at this kind of scenario:

1. There is object of class `common` inside the object of class `source` which is just declared but not instantiated
2. when i pass the object of class `source` to a method map of `program` class

how can i get type of inner object(*common class object*) and instantiate it?

```
public class common
{
    public int x;
}

public class source
{
    public common obj;
}

class program
{
    static void main()
    {
        source obj = new source();
        map(obj);
    }

    void map(source obj)
    {
        **how can i get type of inner object class and instantiate it**
    }
}
```

i used Type.GetType() but is giving empty.

Comment: Please format your code properly

Comment: Even if you get the type, you can't set the fields because they are private. Why would you want to know the type though? You already know about `source` which means you already know that the `obj` field is of type `common`. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: How about using generics and restrict the type to class, new() ? You could then use default() to create a new instance.

Comment: Surely you can just make common obj public?  Are you unable to change source for some reason?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos sorry for not mentioning assume they are public. actually the objects are dynamically passed in my code for auto mapping objects of two classes where i dont know the type of internal object. only objects of outer classes are passed to map them

Comment: @murali.j instead of assuming, just clean up the code and explain what you want *in the question itself*. As it is, the question text is misleading

Comment: Honestly did you even attempt to compile and run this program?  Even after the recent changes it won't run because `main()` should be `Main()`

Comment: @MickyD i already mentioned above this is just to show the scenario i showed as i cannot show the complete code. this is actually implementation of auto mapper

Comment: I'm not talking about _"complete code"_.  I'm talking about the fact that you don't even define a `Main()` method properly.  Now if you said _"whoops! typo!"_ all would be forgiven, but it's obvious you haven't done any testing at all.  Along with **most of the authors of answers on this page**

Comment: @MickyD that happens because everyone just wants to convey Q/A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can get the type by using

```
.GetType()
```

*method but ofcourse my case is different since i stored all fields in*

```
FieldInfo[]
```

*so i used*

```
FieldInfo.FieldType
```

to get the type of my object.
 Once we had our object **type** we can use

```
Activator.CreateInstance(Class Type);
```

to create the instance of class.

Answer (score 1):

So working implementation of map method:

```
common map(source obj)
{
    var typeOfObj = obj.GetType().GetFields(
        BindingFlags.Public |
        BindingFlags.NonPublic |
        BindingFlags.Instance)
        .First(fi=>fi.Name == "obj");
    return (common) Activator.CreateInstance(typeOfObj.FieldType);
}
```

**ARCHIVED**
If you need get type for `obj.obj` then you have use:

```
void map(source obj){
   obj.obj.GetType() ...
}
```

But since you have not instantiate it yet then you need reflection:

```
var f = typeof(source).GetField("obj");
f.FieldType // contains expected
```

If private field is a problem then you have to iterate by all array of fields resolved by:

```
FieldInfo[] fields = source.GetFields(
                     BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                     BindingFlags.Instance);
```

And locate field named `"obj"`

Comment: 1) private fields 2) When you already know the `source` type you know that `source.obj` is of type common. Why ask for it again?

Comment: He means, that obj.obj is null, your code will run in nullpointerexception, that was his question, how to avoid it. Answer: iterate throur GetProperties()

Comment: The first code example results in a null ref exception.  The second, the call to `GetField` results in `null`

Comment: @MickyD that is why I post 3'd code-block to explore fields regardless of `private` accessor

Comment: Which is a jolly good one, but if  you fix the other two I'd give you a +1 too :)

Answer (score 1):

And if you want to instantiate your received class you can use Activator:

```
Activator.CreateInstance(obj.obj.GetType());
```

Although I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Although that code results in a `NullReferenceException`

Answer (score 1):

correct my understanding if I am wrong.

you want to instantiate the inner `common` object once you instantiated the `source` object. if so you could write an `constructor` inside your `source` which will instantiate your private `common` object. something like this

```
class source
{ 
    common obj;
    public source()
    {
        obj = new common();
    }

}
```

Comment: How does this address _"I am implementing an auto mapper"_?

Comment: @ahamed-ali But i am passing object of source to another class and till then i wont create object of common class. But for the scenario you understood, thats a good approach

Answer (score 0):

Where is the problem on this? No need for reflection:

```
void map(source obj)
{
    obj.obj = new common();
}
```

Basically you can modify any passed object as you want, the only thing you can´t do within your method is to set `obj` to a new instance of `source` for which you´d need the `ref`-keyword. In your case you know the type of the passed object, so I guess you also know what the concerning class consists of and thus the type for the `obj`-property.

Comment: How does this address _"I am implementing an auto mapper"_?

Answer (score 0):

Get type field info from your input object then instantiate the object of that field's type and set the value back to your input object :

```
// Get field info for source.obj
FieldInfo fieldInfo = obj.GetType().GetField("obj", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
// Instantiate object without initializing it
object instance = FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(fieldInfo.FieldType);
// set instantiated object reference to the field source.obj
fieldInfo.SetValue(obj, instance);
```

If you're making "AutoMapper" then this will fit your needs because it doesnt use constructor which in other answers should be the default ( parameterless ) one.

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oTUtIE) you can compare different methods of instantiating object without default ( parameterless ) constructor.

Full code example that will map recursively :

```
public static void Main()
{
    _genericMapInfo = typeof(Program).GetMethod("map", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
    Test t = null;
    map(ref t);
    Console.WriteLine(t == null); // False
    Console.WriteLine(t.A); // Hello World!
    Console.WriteLine(t.B.A); // 1337
    Console.WriteLine(t.B.B); // Hello World!
}

static MethodInfo _genericMapInfo;

static void map<T>(ref T obj)
    where T : class
{
    if(obj == null)
        obj = (T)FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(T));

    foreach(FieldInfo fInfo in typeof(T).GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public))
    {
        Type fieldType = fInfo.FieldType;   
        TypeCode tCode = Type.GetTypeCode(fInfo.FieldType);
        if(tCode == TypeCode.Object)
        {
            object[] param = new object[] { fInfo.GetValue(obj) };
            _genericMapInfo.MakeGenericMethod(fieldType).Invoke(null, param);
            fInfo.SetValue(obj, param[0]);
        }
        else if(tCode == TypeCode.String)
        {
            fInfo.SetValue(obj, "Hello World!");    
        }
        else if(tCode == TypeCode.Int32)
        {
            fInfo.SetValue(obj, 1337);  
        }

    }
}

public class Test
{
    public string A { get; set; }   
    public TestInside B { get; private set; }

    public Test()
    {
        A = "no siema"; 
    }
}

public class TestInside
{
    public int A { get; private set; }
    public string B { get; set; }   

    public TestInside(int _someInteger)
    {
        A = _someInteger;   
    }
}
```

[Online check](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_csharp_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMUS1hRnhxRHc0TkU)

Comment: Your line should read `FieldInfo fieldInfo = obj.GetType().GetField("obj", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);`.  Fix it and I'll +1 you

Comment: @MickyD Thank you for the hint. Edited it

Comment: Well done!  First answer that actually works and addresses OP's concerns! +1