# Getting Types of all members of a class

Tags: c#, generics, member, system.type

I need to get the type of all members present in a class.

```
    public class Order
    {
        public int OrderID { get; set; }
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public string CustomerID { get; set; }
        public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
        public bool Verified { get; set; }

        public Order(int orderId, int empId, string custId, DateTime orderDate, bool verify)
        {
            this.OrderID = orderId;
            this.EmployeeID = empId;
            this.CustomerID = custId;
            this.OrderDate = orderDate;
            this.Verified = verify;
        }
    }
```

and the value for the class i have added through List

```
            List<dynamic> dy = new List<dynamic>();
            dy.Add(new { OrderID = 11, EmployeeID = 5, CustomerID = "ALFKI", OrderDate = new DateTime(2015,01, 10), Verified = true });
            dy.Add(new { OrderID = 12, EmployeeID = 4, CustomerID = "CDSAW", OrderDate = new DateTime(2015, 02, 12), Verified = true });
            dy.Add(new { OrderID = 13, EmployeeID = 6, CustomerID = "ASDFG", OrderDate = new DateTime(2015, 03, 13), Verified = true });
            dy.Add(new { OrderID = 14, EmployeeID = 3, CustomerID = "XSDAF", OrderDate = new DateTime(2015, 04, 14), Verified = false });
            dy.Add(new { OrderID = 15, EmployeeID = 2, CustomerID = "MNHSD", OrderDate = new DateTime(2015, 05, 15), Verified = true });
            dy.Add(new { OrderID = 16, EmployeeID = 1, CustomerID = "OKJHG", OrderDate = new DateTime(2015, 06, 16), Verified = false });
            return dy;
```

For get the fields types, i tried with the following code.

```
Type type = dataSource.GetElementType();
Type t = typeof(object);
t = type.GetProperty("OrderDate").PropertyType;
```

Its throws an null expression error.

Here OrderDate is DateTime object.

```
Type type = dataSource.GetType();
```

This line, returns System.object.

When try to get the OrderDate field type.

```
type.GetProperty(filterString).PropertyType;
```

returns Null, how to fix this issue.

Online : https://dotnetfiddle.net/zTYJGU

Comment: You mean like described here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536163/how-to-list-all-variables-of-class

Comment: That looks like an inappropriate use of `dynamic`...

Comment: can you define what is `dataSource`?

Comment: Hi Matthew Watson, For the sake, i have used dynamic keywords in List. Do not consider that one, My requirement is to get the type of the fields in the Class. Here dataSource refers the dy list which contains the records of Order class

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you want to get all field and property types in specified type you should know some things.

Every property have it's own backing field. For auto generated property `public int MeProperty { get; set; }` the backing field will have the name `<MeProperty>k__BackingField`.

Knowing this you should consider extracting `FieldInfo` instead of `PropertyInfo`.

Another thing is that you're assuming that `GetProperty` method will extract even hidden ( `private`, `protected` etc.. ) members, which is totally wrong. It expects that you specify level of accessability by using `BindingFlags` enumeration.

After getting all of that knowledge you can just extract all of the fields instad of properties using :

```
var fields = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

After that you can enumerate and get field types :

```
var fieldTypes = fields.Select(f => f.FieldType);
```

Now you `fieldTypes` is `IEnumerable<Type>` containing every field type specified in `type` field.

The real problem is that you want to implement auto-mapper which creates your defined type from a dynamic type. For this I would recommend you to use the solution from [my answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41890819/can-we-instantiate-an-object-of-a-class-just-declared-and-passed-to-a-method-in/41891202#41891202)

**EDIT:**

Using this code :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        foreach(var field in typeof(Order).GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(field.Name);
        }
    }

    public class Order
    {
        public int OrderID { get; set; }
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public string CustomerID { get; set; }
        public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
        public bool Verified { get; set; }

        public Order(int orderId, int empId, string custId, DateTime orderDate, bool verify)
        {
            this.OrderID = orderId;
            this.EmployeeID = empId;
            this.CustomerID = custId;
            this.OrderDate = orderDate;
            this.Verified = verify;
        }
    }
}
```

You should have the same output as :

```
<OrderID>k__BackingField                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
<EmployeeID>k__BackingField                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
<CustomerID>k__BackingField                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
<OrderDate>k__BackingField                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
<Verified>k__BackingField
```

Comment: Hi Rogalsi, I tried with your solution. But i am getting only three fields not the all the fields